# SymPy fails to solve rewritten integral

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

When I use function `f2`, the integral is solved (rather quickly), but contains some floating point constants. Function `f1` does not use a floating point exponent, but fails to compute the integral. It rather re-displays the integral to solve (after a very long time).

So as a new user of `SymPy` I wonder 1) if I use some wrong commands in `f1`? 2) is it possible to make the execution of `SymPy` faster (because it does not really compare to the speed of `Maple` at the moment).

```
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display

init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

def f1():
    x, y = symbols('x y')
    w, h = symbols('w h', real=True, nonzero=True, positive=True)
    result = Integral((1/sqrt(((y-x)**2 + h**2)**3)), (x,0,w), (y,0,w))
    display(result)
    result = integrate((1/sqrt(((y-x)**2 + h**2)**3)), (x,0,w), (y,0,w))
    display(result)

def f2():
    x, y = symbols('x y')
    w, h = symbols('w h', real=True, nonzero=True, positive=True)
    result = Integral(1/(((y-x)**2 + h**2)**1.5), (x,0,w), (y,0,w))
    display(result)
    result = integrate(1/(((y-x)**2 + h**2)**1.5), (x,0,w), (y,0,w))
    display(result)
```

Sympy Version

```
>>> sympy.__version__
>>> '0.7.6.1'
```

Comment: If you install the fastcache and gmpy libraries it will improve SymPy's speed.

Comment: these https://github.com/pbrady/fastcache https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy ones?

Comment: Yes, those are the right ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two integrals you wrote are not exactly the same. You can do

```
In [22]: integrate((1/sqrt(((y-x)**2 + h**2))**3), (x,0,w), (y,0,w))
Out[22]:
          ________
         ╱      2
        ╱      w
  2⋅   ╱   1 + ──
      ╱         2
    ╲╱         h     2
- ──────────────── + ─
         h           h
```

Note the difference in the placement of the `**3`. The reason is

```
In [25]: sqrt(x**3)
Out[25]:
   ____
  ╱  3
╲╱  x

In [26]: sqrt(x)**3
Out[26]:
 3/2
x
```

The two are not equal for general `x`. For your case, they actually are equal, because the expression in the root is positive, but SymPy has failed to notice that.

Comment: but my sqrt argument is a sum of squares which cannot be negative

Comment: Yeah, it should work, but SymPy fails to see this, even when you set the assumptions.

Comment: I figured out that the obtained integral is wrong. The obtained function is negative. The exact solution differs by a -1 multiplication term

Comment: @Matthias wow you're right. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10211) for it.